# Inline styling with hiccup

Tags: html, css, clojure

I have an html document that I generate with clojure hiccup. When I send the file as an attachment to an email, the css gets stripped out. The css is external and being referenced in the head of the file like below:

```
[:head
  [:title "My Title"]
   (include-css "css/mycss.css")]
```

I heard mail servers strip out all external css so it does not interfere with theirs. One solution I was able to fin was to do an inline styling. For example if I have the below html, how do I perform inline styling on it.

```
[:thead
   [:tr [:th "First column"] [:th "Second column"] [:th "Third column"]]]
```

Additionally, feel free to suggest if there is a better answer to what I want to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

hiccup supports attributes right out of the box with the `{}` syntax, so you could simply use this for settings style attributes on elements easily, e.g., `[:p {:style {:color "#E0E0E0"}} "My paragraph"]` will put the color on the paragraph. But I guess in your case, it might be more convenient to put the general style definitions in the head element, using the `style` element. hiccup supports `:style` for this as one would expect, e.g.

```
[:head [:title "My title"]
       [:style "body { padding-top: 60px; }"]].
```