# Idiomatic way to include style section to HTML using hiccup

Tags: clojure, hiccup

I am working on transactional email like the [responsive html email template](https://github.com/leemunroe/responsive-html-email-template/blob/master/email.html).  If I have the CSS in the file `public/css/email.css`, what is the most idiomatic way to include the contents of the `email.css` in the header of html file?  Note that I do not just want a link, but would like to include the contents of the `email.css` in the HTML in the  section.  Do I simply slurp and insert the contents of `email.css` or is there a better way.

Comment: If you are slurpring, make sure to use a resource and not a file. Once you package your application into an uberjar the css is no longer readable like a regular file from the filesystem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inline styling with hiccup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515243/inline-styling-with-hiccup)

Comment: @SteffanWestcott, the inline styles are styles added to each html element, I am asking about inserting *not inline* but a style section to the html header.

Comment: The answer to the linked question illustrates adding styling information to the head element using hiccup syntax.

Comment: @SteffanWestcott, OK, thank you, so the recommendation is to take the CSS file, translate it to hiccup style, then add it into the like that answer.  I was hoping there would be a way to just include the CSS as is and use the styles in the html.